# reload web app on orientation change

Tags: javascript, css

Simple problem.  I have tried different search phrases. The most recent I tried is "reload web app on orientation change"

I *KNOW* or *DEEPLY SUSPECT* someone(s) have asked this question before on Stackoverflow but the search results do not answer my simple question.

1) I have a web site that renders fine on a smart phone when holding the phone in landscape view, until...

2) I re-orient the smartphone to a 'portrait' view position, where the phone is in the normal position with the long height of the phone is vertical

Then the web page is *not* using the whole screen.  The page stays the *exact same height* as it was with the phone held 'sideways' in landscape mode. What I see is the page only using the top 2/5ths of the smartphone screen.

When I manually reload the page, the web page then *completely fills the entire height of the screen.*

I've added this and it changed nothing:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="height = [pixel_value | 'device-height'],
      width = [pixel_value | 'device-width']" />
```

I prefer forcing a page reload or *something* ?? in javascript when the smart phone's orientation changes.

Because I know for a fact that when I reload the page after rotating the smart phone from landscape to portrait, then (and only then) will my web page use the whole height of the smart phone's screen.

I'm using only pure javascript.

How to reload my web pages in my web app when the smart phone's orientation is changed from landscape to portrait?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very unsophisticated solution you are after but,

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

is a robust way to refresh the page when the user changes the orientation.

You can also use

```
screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

---

Generally you should make sure you write correct HTML/CSS if you want your webpage to be responsive is such settings instead of reverting to this kind of crude solutions

Comment: +1 for Generally you should make sure you write correct HTML/CSS if you want your webpage to be responsive is such settings instead of reverting to this kind of crude solutions

Comment: Not sure here due to my lack of experience how to write correct HTML/CSS to handle this screen orientation change case, I wish I did.  If you have a link that covers this specific case I'd love to know, and probably others on SO; and thanks for your help and for letting me know there's a different more elegant way.  I'm an old guy, 55, and I don't work in a company setting -- when I did this for a living I learned a lot more much more quickly when I had coworkers as resources.  Thanks again.

Comment: I get the point - but 55 doesn't sound old - at least to me. Good luck

Comment: I tried the screen.addEventListener() and it didn't work.  I changed 'screen' to 'window' and that didn't work; so I'm still looking into this.  My guess it the LG smart phone and the Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro tablet   mobile devices I'm using -- both Android -- do not fire the 'orientationchange' event or something.

Comment: use the  *resize* instead - I mentioned above that it's far more reliable

Comment: thought about it but the 'resize' event will get fired on a normal desktop or laptop browser when the browser window is resized,  and I dont need to reload the page for that situation.  Also, I'm not using jquery if that makes any difference.  I could addeventlistener("resize" ... etc)  but it will get fired in every browser resize, not just mobile devices.

Comment: true - you should ask another question about *orientationchange* then